Paul’s handkerchief and the physical medium of miracles?
A number of miracles in the New Testament are not wrought by someone just praying.  Instead, there are often physical intermediaries.  One example is Paul's handkerchief, which could be used to heal people in absence of Paul himself.  Another is the lady touching Jesus' robe.  Jesus also used mud in the eyes of the blind man.  Even when other physical objects are not used, often the healer lays hands on the person being healed, which is still a physical object being used as a medium.  One could even say the words used in a healing prayer are a physical medium, since the words already exist in the person's mind, and God can read everyone's mind, so aren't strictly necessary to exhibit a person's intent to heal.
Why are physical mediums of one sort or another used in the enactment of all the miracles?  Why don't people just think the miracle into existence?

Faith is the medium of many miracles. Many times Jesus said 'Thy faith hath made thee whole' or 'According to thy faith be it unto thee' or 'Wilt thou be made whole ?' Sometimes, Jesus' or an apostle's faith is in evidence. 'Thinking' does not induce miraculous events. God is he who does these things and it is evident that he does so  in answer to faith or by His own initiative for His own reasons.

Yes, faith is a form of thinking.  But, why all the physical things involved in miracles?  From verbal prayer, to laying on of hands, to mud in the eyes, to robes, to handkerchiefs?  What is the point of all the physicality, and what does it mean?

Perhaps the phrasing "think into existence" is a poor word choice. All miracles require "faith" (that of a mustard seed). The fact that mud, fabric, speech, or just pure faith are used... well humans are physical.

There are plenty of miracles that did not have a physical medium.
Healing the Nobleman's son.

So Jesus came again to Cana of Galilee where He had made the water wine. And there was a certain nobleman whose son was sick at Capernaum. When he heard that Jesus had come out of Judea into Galilee, he went to Him and implored Him to come down and heal his son, for he was at the point of death. 48 Then Jesus said to him, “Unless you people see signs and wonders, you will by no means believe.”
The nobleman said to Him, “Sir, come down before my child dies!”
Jesus said to him, “Go your way; your son lives.” So the man believed the word that Jesus spoke to him, and he went his way. And as he was now going down, his servants met him and told him, saying, “Your son lives!” (John 4:46-51)

Healing the servant of the centurion

Now when Jesus had entered Capernaum, a centurion came to Him, pleading with Him, saying, “Lord, my servant is lying at home paralyzed, dreadfully tormented.”
And Jesus said to him, “I will come and heal him.”
The centurion answered and said, “Lord, I am not worthy that You should come under my roof. But only speak a word, and my servant will be healed. For I also am a man under authority, having soldiers under me. And I say to this one, ‘Go,’ and he goes; and to another, ‘Come,’ and he comes; and to my servant, ‘Do this,’ and he does it.”
When Jesus heard it, He marveled, and said to those who followed, “Assuredly, I say to you, I have not found such great faith, not even in Israel! And I say to you that many will come from east and west, and sit down with Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob in the kingdom of heaven. But the sons of the kingdom will be cast out into outer darkness. There will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.” Then Jesus said to the centurion, “Go your way; and as you have believed, so let it be done for you.” And his servant was healed that same hour. (Matthew 8:5-13)

Jesus calms the storm

But He said to them, “Why are you fearful, O you of little faith?” Then He arose and rebuked the winds and the sea, and there was a great calm. So the men marveled, saying, “Who can this be, that even the winds and the sea obey Him? (Matthew 8:26-27)

Jesus healed an invalid man at the pool called Bethesda (John 5:1-9).
Jesus restored a withered hand (Matthew 12:10-13).
Jesus raised Lazarus from the dead (John 11:1-46).
The neverending jar of oil and bin of flour.

For thus says the Lord God of Israel: ‘The bin of flour shall not be used up, nor shall the jar of oil run dry, until the day the Lord sends rain on the earth.’ ”
So she went away and did according to the word of Elijah; and she and he and her household ate for many days. The bin of flour was not used up, nor did the jar of oil run dry, according to the word of the Lord which He spoke by Elijah. (1 Kings 17:14-16)

The Donkey rebukes his rider (Numbers 22:28-30)
Elijah outruns a chariot for 15 miles-ish

Then the hand of the Lord came upon Elijah; and he girded up his loins and ran ahead of Ahab to the entrance of Jezreel. (1 Kings 18:46)

The Sun and Moon stop, so Israel can fight longer.

So the sun stood still,
And the moon stopped,
Till the people had revenge
Upon their enemies.
Is this not written in the Book of Jasher? So the sun stood still in the midst of heaven, and did not hasten to go down for about a whole day. And there has been no day like that, before it or after it, that the Lord heeded the voice of a man; for the Lord fought for Israel. (Joshua 10:13-14)

Philip: Beam me up God

So he commanded the chariot to stand still. And both Philip and the eunuch went down into the water, and he baptized him. Now when they came up out of the water, the Spirit of the Lord caught Philip away, so that the eunuch saw him no more; and he went on his way rejoicing. But Philip was found at Azotus. And passing through, he preached in all the cities till he came to Caesarea. (Acts 8:38-40)

Earthquakes during the Divine Liturgy

And when they had prayed, the place where they were assembled together was shaken; and they were all filled with the Holy Spirit, and they spoke the word of God with boldness. (Acts 4:31)


We can see that many miracles and wonders occurred without physical mediums. Most healings seem to not involve physical things, unless Jesus was attempting to teach multiple observers things. (Is healing a sin? Can I heal and perform miracles on the sabbath? etc)
We also see many miracles in both the new and old testament where pure faith is employed. The sun standing still was faith. Philip being "spirited" away literally was perhaps not faith, but God's will.
At the same time, many miracles involved physical mediums. Wonderworking icons, relics from saints, a scrap of clothing worn by someone... etc.
So, both types of miracles seem to be quite common in the Bible.

Paul's handkerchief and the physical medium of miracles?
God can employ whatever medium he desires to create a miracle: Elijah’s mantle, Peter’s Shadow and Paul’s handkerchief and apron. Jesus even operated a physical healing of a women who simply touched his robe. It is important to understand who these objects represent and the faith in God that some miracle may be obtained.
Good can at times create a miracle without any sort of medium whatsoever.

Then he took the mantle of Elijah that had fallen from him, and struck the water, and said, “Where is the LORD God of Elijah?” And when he also had struck the water, it was divided this way and that; and Elisha crossed over. - 2 Kings 2:9-14 NKJV


… people brought the sick into the streets and laid them on beds and mats so that at least Peter’s shadow might fall on some of them as he passed by. - Acts 5:14-16 NIV


Now God worked unusual miracles by the hands of Paul, so that even handkerchiefs
or aprons were brought from his body to the sick,
and the diseases left them and the evil spirits went out of them. - Acts 19:11-12 NKJV
And it came to pass, as they were burying a man, that, behold, they spied a band of men; and they cast the man into the sepulcher of Elisha. And when the man was let down and touched the bones of Elisha, he revived and stood up on his feet. - 2 KINGS 13:21 KJ21

Miracles may be produced by God in any number of ways when healings are asked for in faith. God can not be undone in the manner (medium) he permits men to use in invoke his healing powers in a legitimate manner.
The body of a saint, a saint’s tomb, a saint’s clothing, apron, handkerchief or even shadow can be mediums through which God ”may” produce miracles, especially when asked for in faith. Ecclesiastical history shows this in a very profound manner, even if some stories are now reduced to legend.
It is true that these mediums are not always necessary for Christ to perform miracles, but they are in fact an aide for the faithful to show that the power of God and his Message (Gospel), through one of His representatives (Prophet, Apostle ...) are enforced in the truth.
St. Paul’s handkerchief leads the faithful to St. Paul and St. Paul in turn lead us to Christ... The symbolism is unique to say the least...
So what is a miracle?

In general, a wonderful thing, the word being so used in classical Latin; in a specific sense, the Latin Vulgate designates by miracula wonders of a peculiar kind, expressed more clearly in the Greek text by the terms terata, dynameis, semeia, i.e., wonders performed by supernatural power as signs of some special mission or gift and explicitly ascribed to God.
These terms are used habitually in the New Testament and express the meaning of miraculum of the Vulgate. Thus St. Peter in his first sermon speaks of Christ as approved of God, dynamesin, kai terasin kai semeiois (Acts 2:22) and St. Paul says that the signs of his Apostleship were wrought, semeiois te kai terasin kai dynamesin (2 Corinthians 12:12). Their united meaning is found in the term erga i.e., works, the word constantly employed in the Gospels to designate the miracles of Christ. The analysis of these terms therefore gives the nature and scope of the miracle. Miracle


Peter's shadow is an interesting case, since shadows are the absence of something physical.
